# How to update packages hashes?

Tags: python, package

I'm sort of new to python, and using Anaconda3-5.1.0 on windows 10
i need to install package kwant, kwant is n't coming for anaconda windows , so i try pip install it ,after some struggle and reading here I found

> kwant-1.3.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

so it match the platform , but this package need scipy and numpy and this comes with anaconda and when i try to pip install kwant ,i get this

```
THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
scipy>=0.14 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/e2/364f0bcc641aeff79d743c732769d5dc31a1e78c27699229431412c4b425/scipy-1.1.0-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=698c6409da58686f2df3d6f815491fd5b4c2de6817a45379517c92366eea208f (from kwant==1.3.2):
    Expected sha256 698c6409da58686f2df3d6f815491fd5b4c2de6817a45379517c92366eea208f
         Got        7072c63cb59028a73b639b354c0054525b002ef2d87a1d45ed7cdeba736b5cc6

numpy>=1.8.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/e4/7d7107bdfb5c33f6cf33cdafea8c27d1209cf0068a6e3e3d3342be6f3578/numpy-1.14.3-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=560e23a12e7599be8e8b67621396c5bc687fd54b48b890adbc71bc5a67333f86 (from kwant==1.3.2):
    Expected sha256 560e23a12e7599be8e8b67621396c5bc687fd54b48b890adbc71bc5a67333f86
         Got        143abb1baa1e5a3427ed09a4f52223aa3947bf76ca25dc4c71da0c2ae663040a
```

as i said I have updated scipy and numpy packages 
so how could i update the HASHES so i can use kwant package

Answer (score 2):

use this to install ,no-cache-dir

```
pip install --no-cache-dir kwant-1.3.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

it means to no use cache to do install , i also get it when i use window 10 .have fun,fix it